# Rails 3.0 Parsing XML and Inserting into Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I'm new to Rails, and am trying to hook up my application to a third-party API (it does't have a gem or plugin for Rails).

Ideally, what I want to be able to do is parse the data (I've heard good things about Nokogiri, but don't know how to use it for what I want to do do. not for lack of trying), and then insert it into the database.

Could anybody provide instructions or point me in the right direction?
Cheers.

**UPDATE:**

**Rake Task:**

```
task :fetch_flyers => :environment do

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))

  events = doc.search('//event')

    events.each do |event|
      @data = Event.new(
        :name           => event.at('name').text,
        :date           => '2011-09-18',
        :time           => '17:00',
        :description    => event.at('long_description').text,
        :address        => event.at('street').text,
        :postcode       => event.at('postcode').text,   
        :price          => event.at('costs').text,
        :user_id        => 1,
        :genre_id       => 1,   
        :town_id        => 1)

    @data.save

    if @data.save
        puts "Success"
    else
        puts "This didn't save, F***"
    end
    end
end
```

I've specified the URL in my code, just hidden it from this code paste.
This code does not work. I can not for the life of me figure out why. All I get is the output in terminal saying **"This didn't save, F****** which means that for some reason the Events are not being saved. Could anyone shed some light on this?

**UPDATE 2:**

I've checked the URL is correct, and have checked the XML is being parsed correctly by using:

```
# Printing Out the Variables to make sure they work.
    puts @name
    puts @date
    puts @time
    puts @desc
    puts @address
    puts @postcode
    puts @price
    puts @user
    puts @genre
    puts @town
```

..Which successfully prints out the values in terminal. However, it still won't insert into my database.

My Model is as follows:

```
belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :genre
    belongs_to :town

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :grid => '90x128#', :list => '140x200#', :full => '400x548'}
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']  
    before_post_process :normalise_file_name

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :date, :presence => true
  validates :time, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
  validates :address, :presence => true
  validates :town, :presence => true
  validates :postcode, :presence => true
  validates :price, :presence => true
  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :viewcount, :presence => true
```

My Development.log file just shows a load of:

```
  [1m[35mTown Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "towns".* FROM "towns" WHERE "towns"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
      [1m[36mTown Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "towns".* FROM "towns" WHERE "towns"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
      [1m[35mTown Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "towns".* FROM "towns" WHERE "towns"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
      [1m[36mTown Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "towns".* FROM "towns" WHERE "towns"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
      [1m[35mTown Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "towns".* FROM "towns" WHERE "towns"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
      [1m[36mTown Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "towns".* FROM "towns" WHERE "towns"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
      [1m[35mTown Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "towns".* FROM "towns" WHERE "towns"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
    .......
```

Every time I try to run the rake task. Does this mean anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using nokogiri you can specify css or xpath selectors, like:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_string)
events = doc.search('//event')
events.each do |event|
  puts event.at('short_description')
end
```

Also, check out nokogiri [intro tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials).

Comment: If I were going to use this with Rails 3, where would I put this? Especially as I would want to run this as a routine cron job every week or so?

Comment: First of all, you should add `gem 'nokogiri'` into Gemfile.  To make routine, you should write rake task and put processing code there or inside model.

Comment: I've updated my question with my recent findings, please check it out!

Comment: You can find why it does not saves, just add something like: `puts @data.errors.collect(&:full_messages).join("\n")` after `puts "This didn't save"`.  I believe, because viewcount attribute is not set and has no default.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put a puts after getting the URL and another after defining `events` to see if there's any data being returned in the first instance. Then I'd check the Event model to see if there are any validations which aren't being met - does the model require a unique user_id or something. I'd also make data a non-instance variable to see if that made a difference. And I'd check that those time formats aren't causing an error in the model.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question, would you mind taking a look at it, and seeing if you could spot anything

Answer (score 0):

I just see your log and find out that your Event model do have has_many realtion with Town Model and also consists town_id column in your event table . 
SO i think that might be the problem as its trying to get the town_id and save the foreign key of town in your event  table . But as it doesn't get any so it's always rollback .
Also if you want then try to **

> @data.save!

**instaed of**

> @data.save

thanks