# Rails Nokogiri Limit Results and Insert into database

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

So what I have right now is a news controller:

news_controller.rb

```
class NewsController < InheritedResources::Base
  def new
      require 'nokogiri'
      doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.rollingstone.com/siteServices/rss/musicNewsAndFeature"))      
      @info = doc.xpath('//item').take(5).map do |i|  
           News.create(:title => i.xpath('title').inner_text, :description => i.xpath('description').inner_text, :link => i.xpath('link').inner_text)
      end
  end
end
```

...which I can call upon in a view like so:

**UPDATE the problem with the limit is right here:**
new.html.erb

```
<%= debug @info.each.first %>
```

**Should be...**

```
<%= debug @info %>
```

the "each.first" was forcing the controller to take the whole thing. Still looking for an alternative method of saving to the database besides using the view.

This works but my problem is two-fold:
1. 7050 news articles are returned (I want the latest 5 or 10)
2.  This isn't really what I want to do at all.

What I want is a ruby script or a rake task something like this that I can run at a command line:

[Rails 3.0 Parsing XML and Inserting into Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345536/rails-3-0-parsing-xml-and-inserting-into-database)

I'm just not sure how to format something like that.  So I want to

1. Retrieve just 5 results from nokogiri
2. Store them in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.rollingstone.com/siteServices/rss/musicNewsAndFeature"))
info = doc.xpath('//item').take(5)
```

now info has only the first 5 items

Comment: I already tried that. Didn't work. @info = doc.xpath('//item').take(5).map do |i| or do i have to drop the map? and if i do that then how do i sort my info?

Comment: I'm not sure what you did. map should only loop over these 5 elements. It should also result in 5 elements. It works fine here.